# How to get user's result/responses from a interactive video (made on H5P) into our own website (lang: python, framework: Django 2)?

Tags: python, django, xapi

I made an interactive video involving questions/answers and embedded the same in my web application. Now, I would like to know how I can get the user's result ? I found that I can use TinCan API to do that but I am using Python 3.7 version which is not supported by TinCan. Please suggest how i can get and store the user's response data (xAPI statements) in the application backend(SQL).

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

xAPI specifies that the statements are JSON, so your SQL backend could simply store that string.

But effectively, storing the user's data means you want to create an LRS - a learning record store. Some information: https://xapi.com/building-a-learning-record-store